# Replacement for "wddx_serialize_value" function in PHP 7.4+

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.4

I am using `wddx_serialize_value` function in my application, now I upgraded to PHP 7.4, But this function is removed from PHP 7.4, So what is the alternative for this function. I don't want to install this extension and all.

Comment: What do the release notes say? Why was it removed? Probably there's a reason and a an alternative to it.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to give an answer, but a Google search suggests that switching to JSON would probably be the best option in the long run if that's possible.

Comment: [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-and-remove-ext-wddx) _...code using the wddx extension would issue deprecation warnings, and/or would have to use the wddx extension from PECL (or somewhere else), or be rewritten._

Comment: As already hinted, it was [removed from core](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.removed-extensions.php) and [moved](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wddx.installation.php) to [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/wddx).

Answer (score 1):

wddx is deprecated because it is insecure.

The proper solution is to switch to json.